# Master Song Database containing popular titles and artists

Tags: usa, csv, music, sql

I'm looking for a song database (sqlite, csv, etc.)  Right now I'm searching through a list of songs from late 60s and early 70s on "http://www.song-database.com/" but I'm searching manually on the internet by clicking through charts on webpages showing week by week top-20 hits across the USA.

I'd like a more complete listing with the title, artist and year at the bare minimum.  It would be wonderful if there's a database containing every song ever published by major labels, with extra fields like "genre" and when and if they became hits, and how big of a hit, and how long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for some other options, I suggest checking out the Wikipedia page on this topic.  You can find it at the link below:

### [List of online music databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases)

I have not used them all, but [**AllMusic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AllMusic) is quite good.

Have fun exploring the others and let us know what you think of them.  You could even do this by using the "answer your own question" feature Stack Exchange has.

Answer (score 3):

The [Million Song Dataset](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/) has this information as well as other features about the song itself. You can download the entire 300GB file as a flat file, or download a 1% sample.

The full field list can be found at their [FAQ](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/faq), and they have code snippets for working with the data in MatLab, SQL, or other programs.

Comment: That is an ENORMOUS file.  The Holy Bible is only 4.13MB of text.  that means this database is about 71,441 times as large.  What's in the file? Obviously something more than text.  perhaps images, videos or the music itself?